# dyld[49745] missing symbol called using c++ swig with node.js by calling a function out of the library

Tags: c++, node.js, 64-bit, swig, arm64

I try to create an example **using SWIG and NodeJS on my M1 (arm64) Mac**,
but I want to mention this as early as possible:
**this issue appears also on an Intel (x64) Mac.**

I create my simple example Files like this:
example.h

```
#pragma once

class Die
{
public:
    Die();
    ~Die();
    int foo(int a);
};

Die* getDie();

//to test if the issue also appears getting a simple functiom without any class context.
extern "C" 
{
    bool getFoo();
}
```

here is the implementation.

example.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "example.h"
int Die::foo(int a) 
{
    std::cout << "foo: running fact from simple_ex" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

Die::Die()
{

}

Die::~Die()
{

}

// out of Class Context
Die* getDie() 
{
    return new Die();
}

extern "C" 
{

    bool getFoo() 
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

my Swig interface is as follows:

example.i

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

then i create my example_warp.cxx file. But as actually the 4.0.2 Version of Swig is not compatible with NodeJs v16.0.0 (read [SWIG support for NodeJS v12 #1520](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1520) and [Prepare SWIG for Node.js v12 #1746](https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/1746)).

Therefore i needed to build swig from source using master branch with the current version (4.1.0). Please keep that in mind.

Swig Command:

```
swig -Wall -c++ -javascript -node example.i
```

Here now some files preparing to create the .node file

package.json
{
"name": "SwigJS",
"version": "0.0.1",
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"install": "node-gyp clean configure build"

```
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "nan": "^2.16.0",
      "node-gyp": "^9.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7"
    }
}
```

the package.json i got from a mate as an example an edited it to work with my project so there may be some lines not really needed by me.

binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "SwigJS",
      "sources": [ "example_wrap.cxx" ],
      "include_dirs" : [ "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

now i build my SwigJS.node file using:

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

it runs through without any errors.

Now i try to access the node-file in my JavaScript but i always get the error message:

missing symbol called

index.js

```
const Swigjs = require("./build/Release/SwigJS.node");

console.log("exports :", Swigjs); //show exports


die = Swigjs.getDie(); //try to get the Class

console.log(die.foo(5)); //call a function from the class
```

the output looks like this:

```
[Running] node "/Users/rolf/Documents/SwigJS/index.js"
exports : {
  getDie: [Function (anonymous)],
  getFoo: [Function (anonymous)],
  Die: [Function: Die]
}
dyld[49745]: missing symbol called

[Done] exited with code=null in 0.12 seconds
```

What i have tried to find the error:

- tried to build the .node file on an x64 architecture to check if it is an arm topic with NodeJS v16:17 on an Intel x64 Mac from a mate.
- installed NodeJS 16.0.0 (first version supporting arm64 on mac)
- as the Github Issues suggest NodeJS version 12 tried to build and run this on an x64 Intel Mac with NodeJS v12.13.0
- tried to force x64 architecture leading to different error but because of incompatible library (x64) using a arm64 mac

all of it (except last mentioned) ended with the same result "missing symbol called"

help would be appreciated big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is an interesting take on a FAQ on this site: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

The role of SWIG is indeed to generate glue code between Node.js and C++ code. But it does *only* that. If you inspect the `.dylib` file that is associated with your NodeJS module using the `nm` command, you will see that it has `U`ndefined references to the C++ functions it wraps.

This is by design. SWIG expects that the code it wraps is somehow already loaded into memory.
There are three approaches to do so:

- Compile example.cpp directly into the SWIG wrapper. Or compile it to a static library first (`example.a`) and link that statically into the wrapper. I think it suffices to add `example.cpp` to the `sources` section of `binding.gyp`
- Compile example.cpp into a library (`example.dylib`) and dynamically link it to the SWIG wrapper. I have not used GYP myself yet, but I think it means adding the following to your `targets` entry in `bindings.gyp`:

```
  'link_settings': {
    'libraries': [
      '-lexample',
    ],
  },
```

- Compile example.cpp into a library (`example.dylib`) and use `dlopen` to load it explicitly. This puts a tremendous burden on your users and is very hard to debug. Do not do this.

Comment: this really solved the issue. The missing example.cpp file was the cause to this error.